# How to Update sql table with data from excel sheet in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, sql-update

I am having problem updating sql table with excel sheet. The fact is that, am working on this small project where the user can first of all export or print out a class list with StudentNumber,SubjectID, ClassScore, ExamScore to excel sheet by clicking a button in vb.net application and then edit the sheet by filling in the ClassScore and ExamScore, then upload the sheet back to sql through vb.net.
The question is how to check if the current StudentNumber or row exist in sql table then update the table else insert a new row.
This is my code using the SQLBulk Copy, left with updating the sql table all in vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog

    If ofd.ShowDialog() <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub
    ' Dim dgv As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
    With ofd
        .Filter = "Excel files(*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Title = "Import data from Excel file"
    End With
    Dim nme As String = ofd.FileName
          Import(nme, dgv)

End Sub
Public Shared Function Import(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal dgv As DataGridView) As Boolean
    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;")
    'MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\vb.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Scores")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    dgv.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
    MyConnection.Close()


    Dim expr As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"


    Dim SQLconn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim ConnString As String = "Data Source=xxxx-PC;Initial Catalog=TryExcel;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxxx"
    Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(expr, MyConnection)
    Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader

    SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString

    Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConnString)
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Scores"

        MyConnection.Open()
        objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
        objDR.Close()
        SQLconn.Close()

    End Using
    Return True
End Function

Private Shared Function safefilename() As String
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Upload_Workbook()

        Dim t As New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub()
                                                dt = New DataTable

                                                dt = New DataTable("Table_Name")
                                                dt.Columns.Add("Column_1")
                                                dt.Columns.Add("Column_2)
                                                dt.Columns.Add("Column_3")
                                                dt.Columns.Add("Column_4")
                                                dt.Columns.Add("Column_5")
                                                dt.Columns.Add("Column_6")
                                                dt.Columns.Add("Column_7")

                                                ds = New DataSet
                                                ds.Tables.Add(dt)

                                                Dim i As Integer

                                                For i = 2 To (Cells(1, 11).Text)

                                                    dr = dt.NewRow
                                                    dr(0) = Cells(i, 1).Text
                                                    dr(1) = Cells(i, 2).Text
                                                    dr(2) = Cells(i, 3).Text
                                                    dr(3) = Cells(i, 4).Text
                                                    dr(4) = Cells(i, 5).Text
                                                    dr(5) = Cells(i, 6).Text
                                                    dr(6) = Cells(i, 7).Text

                                                    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                                                Next i

                                                trans = con.BeginTransaction
                                                Try
                                                    Dim row As Integer

                                                    While (row < dt.Rows.Count)

                                                        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Sheet1_Upload", con, trans)

                                                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column_1", dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(0))
                                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column_2", dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(1))
                                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column_3", dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(2))
                                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column_4", dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(3))
                                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column_5", dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(4))
                                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column_6", dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(5))
                                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column_7", dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(6))
                                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                                                        row = row + 1

                                                    End While

                                                    trans.Commit()

                                                Catch ex As Exception
                                                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                                                    trans.Rollback()
                                                End Try

                                            End Sub))

        t.Start()
End Sub
```

'''''''SQL Stored Procedure'''''''

Create procedure Sheet1_Upload(@Column_1 varchar(50),@Column_2 varchar(50),@Column_3 varchar(50),@Column_4 varchar(50),@Column_5 varchar(50),@Column_6 varchar(50))
as
begin

Insert INTO Table_Name(Column_1,Column_2,Column_3,Column_4,Column_5,Column_6) Values(@Column_1,@Column_2,@Column_3,@Column_4,@Column_5,@Column_6)
end

> Please create this project on Visual Basic>Office/Share Point>Excel 2013 Workbook.[File Path Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9XUe.png)
>   Then open the workbook using another program.

```
    oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oXL.Visible = False
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("D:\workbook.xlsm")
    oWB.Activate()
    oWB.RunAutoMacros(Excel.XlRunAutoMacro.xlAutoOpen)
```

> Use excel Auto_Open macro and sheet changed event in VB.net.

Comment: ok, Not really sure if i get it, buh i will take a close look at it and will feed you with whatever i get. Thanks a lot